# replaced bad 48v forklift battery with car battery, can i use the same charger?

Tags: batteries, charging

I have very limited electrical knowledge and need some help, I had a forklift with 48v 400a battery made up of 24 x 2v batteries, the battery had a few bad cells and was getting old, so instead of trying to spend upward of $4k on new battery I decided to buy 4 deep cycle 12v battery, i did the math and the Amps of the new batteries equate to 87amps

now for the questions, can i use the charger that came with the forklift to charge those battery or would there be any issues due to the different amps and battery configuration?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. The site is for electronics design questions, whereas your is on the use of electronic equipment. As such, it is off-topic for the site and is likely to be closed. This is detailed clearly for you in the site tour. You can choose to delete it yourself before any downvotes reduce your Reputation. Hopefully you'll be able to find another site suitable for a question such as this. Again, welcome.

Comment: `24 x 2v batteries` ... no, it is `24 x 2v cells` .... a battery is made by connecting multiple cells together

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the old battery bank was rated at 400 Ampere-hours (Ah), not Amperes. Your new batteries are rated at 87 Ah which will give about 1/5 the usable time of the original battery bank.  I suggest you use eight 6 Volt "Golf Cart" batteries in series - that should give you about 225 Ah capacity.

If the old and new batteries are both flooded lead-acid types, the original 48 Volt charger should work.